# RDLC loop loading in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, rdlc

In my MVC project I created .aspx page for generating RDLC report but after second or third time after generation of the report the page is in infinite loop.

I already have !IsPostBack check in Page_Load method. Here is my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Info("Export before post back");
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            logger.Info("StartExport");
            //the code for exporting using ReportViewer class
        }
    }
```

The problem I don't get any EventViewer logs, or some exceptions. As I said when I am in debug mode everything works fine, but if I stop debug mode, I can generate the report only once. After that the report in infinite loop loading. Has anyone faced with this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem, the problem was in inconsistent in the DLL libraries. I used older version of the RDLC report and this was the main problem.